# flink logging to file for user code not working

Tags: logging, apache-flink

I'm new to Flink, so this question could be quite simple...

Flink version is 1.5.0.

I created a sample project, copy SocketWindowWordCount from Flink sample code.

My pom.xml file is copy from official site: [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/start/dependencies.html)

I just add some smiple log.info(...) statements. 
No matter I add a log4j.properties in project resources folder, or modify log4j-cli.properties in flink conf folder. The log I added won't output to log file.

log4j-cli.properties modification:

```
log4j.logger.test.flink=INFO, file, console
```

After add this line in log4j-cli.properties, I can see logs in console, but still not appear in both jobmanager.log and taskmanager.log.

I'm using flink run to submit:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster -yn=2 test.jar
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the log location.

On yarn application main page: localhost:8080, click application ID to enter applicaition overview page, then click logs link, just can see jobmananger.err, jobmananger.log, jobmananger.out, 3 links.

But my log is in taskmanager.log. Click locahost:8042 link to enter node manager page, then click "list of containers" on left menu, then can find taskmanager.log in relative container.